# Shiny - How to add vertical / horizontal separator lines in a flowLayout

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to add horizontal and/or vertical rules (depending on the width of the window) between elements of a `flowLayout` in a Shiny app.

If the elements are horizontally stacked, I would like to separate them with vertical rules. And if the window is not wide enough and some elements are vertically stacked, I would like to separate them with horizontal rules.

In this small example, I want to separate the different `verticalLayout` with rules but I don't know (depending on the width of the window) if they will be horizontally or vertically stacked inside the `flowLayout`.

```
# ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
    flowLayout(
        verticalLayout(
            numericInput("num1", label = "Number1", value = 0),
            numericInput("num2", label = "Number2", value = 0)
        ),
        verticalLayout(
            numericInput("num3", label = "Number3", value = 0),
            numericInput("num4", label = "Number4", value = 0)
        ),
        verticalLayout(
            numericInput("num5", label = "Number5", value = 0),
            numericInput("num6", label = "Number6", value = 0)
        ),
        verticalLayout(
            numericInput("num7", label = "Number7", value = 0),
            numericInput("num8", label = "Number8", value = 0)
        )
    )
)
```

Thanks in advance